# Blank html email delivered

Tags: node.js, html-email, email-client

I'm sending an email from a website. It renders fine in Gmail, Outlook, Android, iPhone/iPad...but NOT Apple Mail (Yosemite). I've tried to modify the headers but it doesn't seem to matter. I'm using mailgun at the moment as the sender in case that may matter. Here's a few of the headers...

(For testing I'm also sending a `text/plain` format with a single line to see if it made a difference.)

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

And this is the strangest part, I've never encountered this. This is what the HTML looks like when viewing the source in Apple Mail:

```
<table cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"center" =
width=3D"700">
```

The entire email is blank. I don't even see the one testing line from plain text. Apple Mail is hooked up to a GMail account. The message appears fine when viewing in GMail.

Comment: quoted-printable is not an appropriate encoding for HTML mail.

Comment: That's what I thought too but I can't figure out why it's happening. That header doesn't show up in any other client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this wasn't an issue with Apple Mail per-se. It was an issue with npm mailcomposer which was sending a default transport option encoding of `quoted-printable`. Setting that to `8bit` solved the problem.